# How can I break on multiple clang/ubsan warnings in gdb?

Tags: c, gdb, clang, undefined-behavior

Take the following test program (compiled with clang 3.4 and run under gdb 7.6.1):

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a = INT_MAX + 1;
    int b = INT_MAX + 2;
    printf("Result: a = %d, b = %d\n", a, b);
}
```

I would like to be able to use gdb to automatically stop at the **second** occurrence of undefined behaviour here (`int b = ...`).

If I compile with:

```
clang -fsanitize=undefined -O0 -ggdb3 -o test test.c
```

...then running the program under gdb just results in it running to completion:

```
test.c:6:21: runtime error: signed integer overflow: 2147483647 + 1 cannot be represented in type 'int'
test.c:7:21: runtime error: signed integer overflow: 2147483647 + 2 cannot be represented in type 'int'
Result: a = -2147483648, b = -2147483647
[Inferior 1 (process 24185) exited normally]
```

But if I use:

```
clang -fsanitize=undefined-trap -fsanitize-undefined-trap-on-error -O0 -ggdb3 -o test test.c
```

...then I can't continue past the first occurrence:

```
Program received signal SIGILL, Illegal instruction.
0x0000000000400556 in main () at test.c:6
6       int a = INT_MAX + 1;
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Program terminated with signal SIGILL, Illegal instruction.
The program no longer exists.
```

Is it possible to get gdb to break when (and only when) undefined behaviour is flagged, but to let the program continue otherwise? I'm after a technique that will work not just on this example, but in general, where the offending line might be inside a loop, the values may be determined at runtime, etc.

Comment: Use the first compilation method, insert a breakpoint on `write` and look at the stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On x86-64 the instruction that causes SIGILL and stops a program is `ud2` (http://asm.inightmare.org/opcodelst/index.php?op=UD2).  In order to archive your goal you can change in gdb handling of SIGILL and use jumping (you need to add 2 to $pc on x86_64):

This is how the instruction `ud2`  is placed in the code of your test program on x86_64:

```
   0x00000000004004f0 <+32>:    0f 85 02 00 00 00       jne    0x4004f8 <main+40>
=> 0x00000000004004f6 <+38>:    0f 0b   ud2
   0x00000000004004f8 <+40>:    b8 ff ff ff 7f  mov    $0x7fffffff,%eax
```

These are gdb commands that is necessary to use:

```
handle SIGILL stop print nopass
set $pc = $pc + 2
```

This is an example for your test program:

```
$ gdb -q ./test
Reading symbols from /home/test...done.
(gdb) handle SIGILL stop print nopass
Signal        Stop      Print   Pass to program Description
SIGILL        Yes       Yes     No              Illegal instruction
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/test

Program received signal SIGILL, Illegal instruction.
0x00000000004004f6 in main () at test.c:6
6         int a = INT_MAX + 1;
(gdb) set $pc = $pc + 2
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Program received signal SIGILL, Illegal instruction.
0x000000000040051f in main () at test.c:7
7         int b = INT_MAX + 2;
(gdb) set $pc = $pc + 2
(gdb) c
Continuing.
Result: a = -2147483648, b = -2147483647
[Inferior 1 (process 7898) exited normally]
(gdb)
```

Useful links:

- http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Jumping.html#Jumping
- http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Signals.html#Signals